# How do I set an element's class using data-win-bind

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm trying to dynamically set the class of a listview item template:

```
<div id="semanticZoomTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
    <h1 class="semanticZoomItem-Text" data-win-bind="innerText:title;class:contains"></h1>
</div>
```

But [data-win-bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh440968.aspx) fails to do anything when 'class' is present as a property-name.

Is there a correct way to styling specific items in a listview if indeed I can't change the class with data-win-bind?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the JavaScript class property, which is not called "**class**", but "**className**".

Comment: Thanks! data-win-bind="innerText:title;className:contains" works great.

Comment: Hi @ChristiaanV, do you know if using `class="other" data-win-bind="className:contains"` replaces the class attribute or appends the binding to the existing?

Comment: By default it overrides the "other" class. I know that you can build converters, which you can add in your binding, but don't know exactly if you can build a converter that can make the class append.